# Spectral density of Liouville CFTs

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I find the spectral density of Liouville CFT in two papers, but they are quite different. It's confusing for me.

In more details, the eq. (1.4) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00423 says that the spectral density of  Liouville CFT is given by polynomial dependence, however, the eq. (104) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5205 suggests that it is given by exponential dependence (Cardy formula).

What does cause this difference? normalization? including non-physical states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial density of Yin et al is correct. It is the density of primary states.

Cardy's formula is supposed to give the density of all states, not just primary states, and it is exponential. Of course there are many more descendent states than primary states.

What I do not understand in your second reference is why they find Cardy's formula when computing the density of primary states, and why they identify the density of primary states in Liouville theory with the Plancherel measure on their quantum group. These look like two mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you know, but I'd like to mention that Cardy formula can be generalized to the spectrum of primaries only by replacing c by c-1 when considering a compact CFT with c>1. This is shown as eq.(53) in <https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05855 >. Therefore, I think it's not unusual to find Cardy formula when computing the density of primaries. Nevertheless, I agree with you since Liouville CFT is not a compact CFT. (I can't understand the statement by Verlinde et al, though.)

Comment: Good point. I think that the behaviour of the density of states is actually controlled by the dimension of the ground state. The exponential behaviour that you quote is for CFTs whose ground state has dimension zero. In Liouville theory the ground state has dimension $\frac{c-1}{24}$, hence the difference.

Comment: Which does make the density special, the dimension $\frac{c-1}{24}$ or the vacuum state? In other words, which is special, polynomial or exponential? I think you mean the spectral density of Liouville CFT is unique, right?

Comment: I think the density of primary states behaves as $e^{2\pi\sqrt{(c-1-24\Delta_0)\frac{\Delta}{6}}}$ where $\Delta_0$ is the dimension of the ground state, and for Liouville theory the exponential behaviour disappears because $\Delta_0=\frac{c-1}{24}$. The density of all states is still exponential though.